# How do I keep Apple Pay enabled while also having Automatically Check for updates unchecked?

Tags: macos, software-update, apple-pay

Im now on Monterrey 12.6.2 and Safari 16.2. Before these updates ive always kept System Preferences, Software Update, Automatically Check for Updates, unchecked as I like to do this manually myself.  However, now, with this option unchecked, my Apple Pay on the MBP is showing disabled.  Apple Pay will not activate now unless I have the Automatically check for updates checked.

Is there a way to have the the check for updates unchecked and have Apple Pay active like I use to??

Automatically check for updates unchecked

[image: Automatically check for updates unchecked]

Apple Pay disabled

[image: Apple Pay disabled]

Automatically check for updates checked

[image: Ck for updated checked]

Apple Pay enabled

[image: Apple Pay enabled]

Comment: What if you uncheck Install system data/security? I'd assume that's the one that's locking you out, but it's worth checking.

Comment: if I uncheck install system data/security and keep check for updates checked, Apple Pay is disabled.  If I then uncheck check for updates with install system data files/security unchecked, that one (system data files/security) gets greyed out and Apple Pay is still disabled.